# Parse an integer to a float using Nom

Tags: rust, nom

Nom has an [example of parsing a floating point number](https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/3000d54cc643289cc1d75e48a0f49a659a8dbe4a/tests/float.rs#L9-L20):

```
named!(unsigned_float <f32>, map_res!(
  map_res!(
    recognize!(
      alt!(
        delimited!(digit, tag!("."), opt!(complete!(digit))) |
        delimited!(opt!(digit), tag!("."), digit)
      )
    ),
    str::from_utf8
  ),
  FromStr::from_str
));
```

I want to extend this example to also support parsing `"123"` to `123.0`. I've tried something like this with no luck:

```
named!(unsigned_float_v1 <f32>,
    map_res!(
        map_res!(
            alt!(
                recognize!(
                    alt!(
                        delimited!(digit, tag!("."), opt!(complete!(digit))) |
                        delimited!(opt!(digit), tag!("."), digit)
                    )
                ) |
                ws!(digit)
            ),
            str::from_utf8
        ),
        FromStr::from_str
    )
);

named!(unsigned_float_v2 <f32>,
    map_res!(
        map_res!(
            recognize!(
                alt!(
                    delimited!(digit, tag!("."), opt!(complete!(digit))) |
                    delimited!(opt!(digit), tag!("."), digit) |
                    digit
                )
            ),
            str::from_utf8
        ),
        FromStr::from_str
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `tag!(".")` with `complete!` too, as follows:

```
named!(unsigned_float_v2 <f32>,
    map_res!(
        map_res!(
            recognize!(
                alt!(
                    delimited!(digit, complete!(tag!(".")), opt!(complete!(digit))) |
                    delimited!(opt!(digit), complete!(tag!("."), digit) |
                    digit
                )
            ),
            str::from_utf8
        ),
        FromStr::from_str
    )
);
```

If the input is `123`, the `tag!` would return `Incomplete` because it cannot decide if the next input is a `.`